# Блок не расстягивается,по высоте к вложенным Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Document

```
<div class="row background-logo">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-10">
    <div class="logo">
      <h1>g</h1>
      <div class="triangle-logo"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-title">
      <p>Good Inc.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-md-offset-3
  col-sm-offset-2 newsletter">
    <p>Newsletter</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Нужно,чтобы row имел высоту вложенных блоков ,а не нулевую и чтобы ему можно было задать background-color равный ширине браузера.[image: Страница]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: .row{display:table; clear:both;} or .row:after{display:table; clear:both; content:'';}

Answer (score 0):

Вот твое меню, ты либо не подключил `bootstrap`, либо что-то сделал с `.row`. Почитай внимательно документацию. 
Ссылка как я сделал.

> http://codepen.io/geek_of_cola/pen/gwJLyo

```css
.header_bar {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.header_bar .header_bar-background-black {
  background: #000;
  min-height: 50px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.header_bar .header_bar-background-black p {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="header_bar">
  <div class="container header_bar-background-black">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3 header_logo">
        <p>logo</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-3 header_some-content">
        <p>some content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Я точно подключил bootstrap и точно не трогал row и все что с ним связанно.